# How do we Close a custom UserControl as Dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I designed a UserControl and planning to display this as popup window when click a button in MainWindow .

I followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262115/how-do-you-display-a-custom-usercontrol-as-a-dialog). For open usercontrol as dialog window.

```
private void btnInstApp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window objWindow = new Window
        {
            Title = "Title 12345",
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen,
            AllowsTransparency=true,
            Width = 500,
            Height = 200,
            Content = new ucInstrumentApp()
        };

        objWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I used `None` as `WindowStyle`. And designed a custom close button in UserControl for close the popup/dialog window. I tried the given below code. But it's not working.

```
 private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {      
        //this.Close(); //:not working      
        Window objWindow = new Window
        {               
            Content = new ucInstrumentApp()
        };

        objWindow.Close();
 }
```

I am new to WPF/Windows forms. Can you guys guide me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the parent `Window` from your current `UserControl` and then `Close` it.

One solution to achieve such a thing could be the following one :

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow((DependencyObject)sender);
         if (parentWindow != null)
         {
             parentWindow.Close();
         }
    }
```

As you can see, it's based on the [Window.GetWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.getwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, here's its description :

> Returns a reference to the Window object that hosts the content tree
>   within which the dependency object is located.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{     
    this.Close();
}
```

That should work :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. It's not working for `UserControls` & It will work for `Forms` only. i got a error like this `....does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument...`