# How to prevent resizing of user control in WPF

Tags: wpf, resize, controls

How to prevent for resizing the user control in WPF. there is option for controling in windows control. Please help me on this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable resizing of user control in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306082/how-to-disable-resizing-of-user-control-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minWidth=MaxWidth=Some value and MinHeight=MaxHeight=somevalue. this should prevent re-sizing a control in wpf. You can access these properties in XAML.