# OpenFileDialog is displayed outside windows application that launches it

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

To avoid exception on STA, this is the code I used to launch OpenFileDialog. It works fine except that the dialog is opened outside the application. Is there a way I can set the parent/handle such that the OpenFileDialog is displayed inside the application ? Appreciate your help.

```
Thread t = new Thread ((ThreadStart)(() => {

    OpenFileDialog openFileDialogBrowser = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialogBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        selectedPath = openFileDialogBrowser.FileName;

    }
}));

// Run your code from a thread that joins the STA Thread
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
t.Join();
Console.WriteLine(selectedPath);
```

If I use without creating a new thread, I get this exception:

> "Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."

Comment: Is your main thread STA? Do you have forms running OK on any thread? What happens if you run the dialog box on that thread? That thread should be STA for winforms to work properly so you should be able to use that.

Comment: Launch it from a window? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1262128/5228202

Comment: Dialogs always require an owner window, one they can stay on top of.  Winforms lets you use Show() without specifying the owner, that usually comes to a good end because it can find one by itself.  Except when it can't, like here, that thread doesn't own any other windows at all so the desktop window becomes the owner.  You *must* have a valid window and the code *must* run on the UI thread, this hack does not solve any problems.

Comment: A windows form project has a Program.cs file with following :         [STAThread]
        static void Main().  Your main project is not a form project.  The error message says you need the [STAThread] above main.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Main thread is not STA, yes I am able to launch forms. This openFileDialog is being launched from a Form and it works fine with this new thread creation but is diplayed outside the application. I have to do Alt Tab to access the OpenFileDialog.